# Chrome user login for one app only

Tags: google-account

I use Google Chrome and I would like to give permission for some people to use my account but only for one / two Google apps like [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com) and [Google Meet](https://meet.google.com). I don't want to allow them with full access to my Gmail, etc. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid you can't do that. You can certainly share one or more of your calendars to a different account, but not all apps support sharing like that.

Google Chrome has nothing to do with it.